# Embedding a Java applet in an html file

Tags: java, html, applet, embed

I've been looking all over trying to find out how to embed a java applet (as a .jar file) into an html file.

As for my applet code:

```
public class Test extends JApplet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6720807697934652522L;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("TESTING", 50, 50);
    }

}
```

As for my html file:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="200" width="400">
  <param name="code" value="Test.class" />
  <param name="archive" value="TestApplet.jar" />
  Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>
```

I have seen that the applet tag is now deprecated, and this is the way I should be doing it now. However, it still isn't working for me. I have the Jar, TestApplet.jar, and the html file in the same folder.

Comment: What about it isn't working? Any errors, browser messages? What browser are you opening the html file with?

Comment: No errors, it just shows up with the "Applet failed to run. No Java plug-in was found." Since I wrote that in the html. I've tried opening in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: Ok, I ask because your example works for me as-is, in Firefox. I don't know how to change the security settings for it to work in Chrome or IE, but after adding an exception in the "Java Control Panel" -> "Security" -> "Edit Site List..." -> <put the full path of the html file>, the applet opens fine in Firefox.